What's the deal with "intelligibility"?
Consistently, in english-language literature on the history of philosophy, I see philosophers like Plato, Hegel, Heidegger, etc. get interpreted in terms of this concept "intelligibility." This concept does not, so far as I can see, appear in these thinkers' works themselves, but it seems to be taken for granted that it translates not only some aspect of their thinking but the whole essence of what they were trying to get at. I've also never seen the concept of intelligibility get interrogated in its own right: it seems to me that it would be rather difficult to pin down.
Does anyone know where this discourse of "intelligibility" got started? It seems like it must be a 20th Century thing, and probably an Anglosphere thing. Thanks!

A couple of refs that make your point would be in order

Without some quotes, it's hard to know if you are talking about a technical term "intelligibility" or about the non-technical use of the word in a lot of modern philosophy to criticize a philosophical claim or explanation as having no meaning that anyone can genuinely grasp or understand.

Though I may be stating the obvious, writing is not merely a form of self-expression. It's a form of communication, and communication is a social activity that depends on people being able to reach each other intellectually. I have to say things that you can understand and you have to say things that I can understand, otherwise there is no possibility of communication.
'Intelligibility' merely means using language that others find accessible and interpretable. This is a particular issue in philosophy. Philosophers are generally trying to communicate ideas that lie outside common understanding. Philosophy isn't small talk, business chatter, or spoken entertainment, all of which rest heavily on shared knowledge and culture. Philosophers are trying to get people to think about things they don't normally think about, and to see things in ways they don't normally see them, so they have to take care not to put too heavy a cognitive load on the people who read them. Further, philosophers often spend large amounts of time crafting their ideas in isolation. This is (I think) necessary to the process — it's hard to think clearly in the hustle and bustle of society — but it alienates them from normal conversational modes, so that they can slip into disciplinary jargon or use words or phrases in idiosyncratic or alt-definition ways ('alt-definition' being an example of idiosyncratic phrasing). That can be disconcerting for a reader who anticipates conventional words and usage.
One of the skills we have to develop when we read or write philosophy is distinguishing between three conditions:

Communication problems that arise when one is trying to express a deep and subtle concept that one understands well
Communication problems that arise when one is trying to express a concept that isn't yet fully developed
Communication problems that arise when one is trying (intentionally or not) to obscure a lack of proper understanding

In the first case the goal is to make yourself more intelligible so that others can see what you see; in the second case the goal is to make yourself more intelligible so that others can help you develop the idea; in the third case the goal is to make yourself unintelligible to save face. People who read philosophy want to encourage the first two and weed out the last, so intelligibility becomes a significant concern in the discipline.
I hope that was intelligible. If not, talk to me in comments…

Well, there's this article about Dreyfus' ideas of intelligibility as considered via the ideas of Heidegger: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00071773.2018.1507419 (also see sci-hub)

By “intelligibility” I mean simply what Heidegger calls “Verständlichkeit”. The intelligible is the “understandable”. As we have seen, things are understood in practical intelligibility insofar as they belong to totalities of reference – or to put it more simply, because they belong to a world. To see why discursive articulation is necessary to practical intelligibility, the role of discourse in articulating totalities of reference must be established.

The author makes a few claims about intelligibility but does not actually define the word; to say intelligibility is about how objects belong to a "totality of reference," or that it requires discourse to reveal, does not actually say what it is.
I think the first answer is that we simply don't know. Intelligibility is one of those words that is so fundamental to how we think that to really define it we'd have to really understand how we think, and we don't. It is certainly related to how objects fit into a world, and it is exposed through discourse.
It's also related to how effectively you can solve problems; to understand a topic means you can solve problems related to that topic. If you understand what someone is saying - that is, if they are intelligible to you - this means that you can make correct inferences based on what they have said. You are able to solve the problem of making such inferences, in the same way that someone who understands differential equations is able to solve many (but not all!) problems of making inferences related to differential equations. The greater the degree of understanding, the more problems they can solve.
Someone tells you about floobles, and you don't know what they mean. They tell you floobles weigh 20 to 50 grams, and you understand a little bit about floobles. You can deduce from this that floobles must be physical objects made of matter. They tell you floobles are long and thin, and now you can infer that they might fit through small apertures, that they lack spherical symmetry, and so on; you understand more. They tell you floobles have two to four tines, and are used for eating meat; you realize they are talking about forks, and now you can make a whole range of inferences about floobles - how much they typically cost, where they are stored, and so on, and now you have a great deal of understanding.

"we'd have to really understand how we think" -- but isn't that one of the goals of philosophy? Philosophy frequently runs into recursive problems like this (consider "What the tortoise said to the hare")

@Barmar If we really understood how we think, we would be able to model it with mathematics... and run that mathematics on a computer to simulate human (or at least humanlike) thinking. We aren't there yet. We're getting there, but not yet.

Yeah, we have a full map of the fruit fly connectome now. So we're a hop, skip and a jump from the human brain.

@Barmar There's a lot more to how even a fruit fly thinks than just the connectome. The brain has lots of chemical signaling processes that we don't fully understand (that don't even use the synapses), glial cells play a role, and we do not fully understand the dynamics of how synapses change during learning. What we're really lacking is, beyond all these details (that we don't fully know), a theory of the organizing principles, the reasons for the details.

True, but we have to start somewhere. Remember when scientists naively thought that mapping the genome would be the "blueprint for a human", and when they thought "junk DNA" didn't have any function?
